# What is a good free Linux FTP backup solution?

Tags: linux, backup, ftp, nas

I have the need for a backup solution that will let me run local incremental backups and then synchronize the backup with a remote folder over FTP.  I have found several solutions that would allow me to do something like this but requires that my remote connection use SSH, rsync, or SFTP.  Unfortunately, FTP is my ONLY option as the remote drive is a NAS drive with only FTP capabilities.  Is there some sort of utility available, or a script I could write that would do the following:

1. Determine the files that have
   changed since the last backup
2. Zip then encrypt the target file
3. Copy the encrypted files to the
   local backup folder
4. Synchronize the backup files with
   the remote FTP folder

Any help is appreciated,

Mike

Comment: Cross-posting is not a good idea anywhere on the web.

Comment: @Kevin - actually, this is good for Super User, but can probably be answered as well on Server Fault. In such case, cross posting is ok. You will only get answers from a different point of view. User oriented here, and more professional solutions on Server Fault. [Link to the Server Fault question.](http://serverfault.com/questions/170719/what-is-a-good-free-linux-ftp-backup-solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) can send backups to ftp. It can do incremental backups, can produce plain tarballs or gpg-encrypted backups as well.

Comment: Could not get duplicity going. Could not get past the error:  No module named 'paramiko'

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpsync/ it doesn't do everything but takes care of the difficult ftp-syncing part. The other parts is not hard to script yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TimeDrive](http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/science-and-technology/time-drive). Works great with this kind of setup.